# Too X that vs so X that

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Saw this sentence recently and the "too" is bothering me.

> Nothing should be stacked too high that it might cover a fire suppression system or sprinkler head.

I can't give a rule as to why, but it feels like it should be "so high".

Am I mistaken or is "too" incorrect here?

Comment: What were you reading? 'Too' here feels somewhat old-fashioned to me, like I might not bat an eyelash to see in Sherlock Holmes stories or the Hobbit.

Comment: @AeonAkechi Corporate fire safety training

Comment: _Too_ is a negative. _Too high_ means _so high that `Not S`_, where `S` is some expected result. _Too_ doesn't take a _that_ complement clause. But _so_ does. The idiom is _so `Adj` that `S`_ or _such (a) `NP` that `S`_. _So_ and _such_ mean the same but work with different kinds of words. So it's probly a mistake, with somebody typing _too_ instead of _so_, the way they might type _to_ instead of _too_.

Comment: It's poorly worded.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Too* is a negative. *Too high* means *so high that `Not S`*, where `S` is some expected result. *Too* doesn't take a *that* complement clause. But *so* does. The idiom is *so `Adj` that `S`* or *such (a) `NP` that `S`*. *So* and *such* mean the same but work with different kinds of words. So it's probly a mistake, with somebody typing *too* instead of *so*, the way they might type *to* instead of *too*.